# How to return string from interface to setonclicklistener

Tags: java, android, oop

I'm trying to learn android development and i was learning about the  recyclerView. I want to send a string via an interface when a list item is clicked but I dont know how to do that.Can anyone please tell me what to do to achieve this.
This is my java code of the custom recyclerview adapter that I've created.

```
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.TextView;

import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView;

public class CustomAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<CustomAdapter.ViewHolder> {

    private String[] localDataSet;
    private newsOnCkicked k;

    /**
     * Provide a reference to the type of views that you are using
     * (custom ViewHolder).
     */
    public static class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        private final TextView textView;

        public ViewHolder(View view) {
            super(view);
            // Define click listener for the ViewHolder's View

            textView = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.textView2);
        }

        public TextView getTextView() {
            return textView;
        }
    }

    /**
     * Initialize the dataset of the Adapter.
     *
     * @param dataSet String[] containing the data to populate views to be used
     * by RecyclerView.
     */
    public CustomAdapter(String[] dataSet,newsOnCkicked k) {
        localDataSet = dataSet;
        this.k=k;
    }

    // Create new views (invoked by the layout manager)
    @Override
    public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup viewGroup, int viewType) {
        // Create a new view, which defines the UI of the list item
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext())
                .inflate(R.layout.mylayout, viewGroup, false);
        RecyclerView.ViewHolder v=new ViewHolder(view);
        view.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                k.onItemClicked(localDataSet[v.getAdapterPosition()]);
            }
        });
        return new ViewHolder(view);
    }

    // Replace the contents of a view (invoked by the layout manager)
    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder viewHolder, final int position) {

        // Get element from your dataset at this position and replace the
        // contents of the view with that element
        viewHolder.getTextView().setText(localDataSet[viewHolder.getAdapterPosition()]);
    }

    // Return the size of your dataset (invoked by the layout manager)
    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return localDataSet.length;
    }
}
interface newsOnCkicked extends View.OnClickListener {
    String onItemClicked(String s);
}
```

Kindly help me to figure this out!!

Comment: what exactly is not working.this code seems fine to me exccept for having to extend Onclicklistener on the interface id have this instead   ` interface newsOnCkicked {
        void onItemClicked(String s);
    }`

Answer (score 0):

This code seems fine except for these parts i noted you had to do
1)Extending onclick listener
2)The function and position of your interface.

First place your interface in a separate file or inside the adapter class,remove the extends and replace the string to return void:

```
   interface newsOnCkicked {
        void onItemClicked(String s);
    }
```

Then call it like this from your activity

```
 new RecyclerView(this)/* <- your recyclerview*/.setAdapter(new CustomAdapter(new String[20]/*your array*/, new CustomAdapter.newsOnCkicked() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClicked(String s) {
            //here s is your clicked string
        }
    }));
```

The code should look more or less like below:

```
public class CustomAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<CustomAdapter.ViewHolder> {

    private String[] localDataSet;
    private newsOnCkicked k;

    /**
     * Provide a reference to the type of views that you are using
     * (custom ViewHolder).
     */
    public static class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        private final TextView textView;

        public ViewHolder(View view) {
            super(view);
            // Define click listener for the ViewHolder's View

            textView = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.textView2);
        }

        public TextView getTextView() {
            return textView;
        }
    }

    /**
     * Initialize the dataset of the Adapter.
     *
     * @param dataSet String[] containing the data to populate views to be used
     * by RecyclerView.
     */
    public CustomAdapter(String[] dataSet,newsOnCkicked k) {
        localDataSet = dataSet;
        this.k=k;
    }

    // Create new views (invoked by the layout manager)
    @Override
    public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup viewGroup, int viewType) {
        // Create a new view, which defines the UI of the list item
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext())
                .inflate(R.layout.mylayout, viewGroup, false);
        RecyclerView.ViewHolder v=new ViewHolder(view);
        view.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                k.onItemClicked(localDataSet[v.getAdapterPosition()]);
            }
        });
        return new ViewHolder(view);
    }

    // Replace the contents of a view (invoked by the layout manager)
    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder viewHolder, final int position) {

        // Get element from your dataset at this position and replace the
        // contents of the view with that element
        viewHolder.getTextView().setText(localDataSet[viewHolder.getAdapterPosition()]);
    }

    // Return the size of your dataset (invoked by the layout manager)
    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return localDataSet.length;
    }

    interface newsOnCkicked {
        void onItemClicked(String s);
    }
    
    
}
```